# git-svn upstream status check

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

in a git-svn repo,

```
git status
```

doesn't show the usual

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is behind 'origin/git-svn' by 1 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

is there a way to configure the upstream differently so that the status will reflect the remote?

currently, i just consistently run

```
git svn rebase
```

to check for changes, but it would be nice to know if I have to rebase or not in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe 'git svn fetch' will pull in the information without updating your current git branch that sits ontop the 'svn branch'.  Thus, if you do a 'git fetch' it should have the information.  'git status' still won't show it by default, however.  But thinks like gitk and 'git svn info' and 'git log' will help you figure out how far behind you are without actually doing the rebase.